18 V AC to 5 V DC circuit design with battery
I’ll start by saying I have little understanding of electronic circuits. I have an old door phone to which I have connected a wireless switch in order to be able to open my door with a remote control. I power said wireless switch with an old 5 V phone charger connected to a wall socket nearby. I am tired of having an ugly cable showing all the time and I decided to design a circuit in order to attach an 18650 battery to it. Now, the problem I’m facing is that I have two cables coming from downstairs that carry 18 V AC. These cables when connected together allow the electric strike to release the door. I have wired the wireless switch to connect these two cables together.
The circuit that I’m thinking based on my little knowledge is:

Connect a bridge rectifier to the 18 V AC to get DC voltage
Connect a capacitor to smooth the DC ripple created by the bridge rectifier
Connect buck converter to lower the voltage to 5 V DC
Connect the 18650 battery with a BMS to the 5 V output of the buck converter
Power the wireless switch from the BMS

Wireless switch specs:

Input voltage: DC 4-12 V
Working Current: 70-130 mA (measured 110 mA)
Standby Current: 7-9 mA (measured 4.5 mA)
eBay listing: https://www.ebay.com/itm/182812387343

I’ve decided to use a battery to power the switch because I only have a set of wires giving 18 V AC and when connected this voltage drops to 0 which will effectively kill the operation of the wireless switch. Maybe a capacitor could do the trick as the remote will be pressed for max 10 seconds at a time.
Can you help me design a circuit with the proper components and their values for my application?
Edit to clarify: Basically I need to convert 18VAC to appropriate DC voltage to keep the 18650 battery charged to power a wireless switch

Please ask a question you need an answer (i.e. with what exactly you need help with, instead of if anyone can help). And where your plan goes horribly wrong is that you cannot connect a lithium battery through a BMS to 5V buck regulator. Your regulator will drive all current it possibly can into battery and it still can't reach 5V so it will likely give up trying, unless the BMS cuts off due to overcurrent and overvoltage. And mAh is a measure of energy capacity, not consumed current.

Why do you need you put the wireless switch in this location?

you need a battery protection or charging module, since feeding it 5v can explode the battery.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Rather than a buck converter you need a module that’s designed specifically for charging an 18650.  That shouldn’t be too hard to find.  18VAC will rectify to about 25V as the DC voltage will reflect the peak of each AC cycle.  This may be too high for some charger modules so you might need an additional regulator to drop to a lower voltage.  This could be a buck converter or a linear regulator would do since the circuit will only draw a few mA.
